# Down down list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating a table in excel to capture metadata and I want to allow a user to select options from a drop down list(1=yes,2=no,999=missing).

Comment: Being a bit more specific will help getting a useful answer :)

Answer (score 2):

> To add a list to a worksheet place the
> cursor in the required cell and then
> select Data | Validation | Settings.
> In the dialog box select 'Allow: List'
> and ensure the 'In-cell dropdown' box
> is ticked.
>
> The source data refers to a
> range of cells containing the
> selection of options (e.g. H12:H15).

[Source](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xldropdown.htm)

You can then hide the column containing the values.

---

From the same *Data Validation* window you can choose an *Error Alert* to appear if something other than the available values is entered.

*Remember, there is nothing to stop a user from removing this validation from the spreadsheet, unless you protect the sheet or cell(s).*

Answer (score 0):

In Excel- select the Data header tab
Go to Data Validation
Settings
Allow  -  List

Source -  Select the area of a spreadsheet that has the drop down choices

Comment: Your answer seems to be incomplete. Also, were you aware this question is 4-years old?